# Correct way to design endpoints

Tags: rest, url-design

I am designing REST. I have user and user has contacts of different types. What should my endpoints be like according to REST?

This looks reasonable:

```
GET /users/:id/contacts
```

```
GET /contacts
```

On users endpoint I check contacts for another user and on contacts endpoint I check logged in user in contacts, but then if I need to get all contacts for all users I need to make a filter:

```
GET /contacts?user_id=:id
```

And make this endpoint return all contacts. And this makes endpoint on users redundant.

What is correct way to do it according to REST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What should my endpoints be like according to REST? [...] What is correct way to do it according to REST?

That's a *misconception*.

The REST architecture doesn't enforce any URI design <sup>(see notes below)</sup>. It's totally up to you to pick the URIs that better identify your resources.

---

The URI syntax is defined in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). As general rule, the path is organized in hierarchical form (with segments separated by `/`) and can contain non-hierarchical data in the query component (starting with `?`).

So `/users/{id}/contacts` seems to be just fine to identify *a collection of contacts that belongs to a particular user*.

---

<sup>**Note 1:** The REST architectural style is described in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy T. Fielding's dissertation and it defines a set of constraints that must be followed by the applications that follow such architecture. However it says nothing about what the URIs must be like.</sup>

<sup>**Note 2:** The *examples* of a [popular article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) written by Martin Fowler explaining a model defined by Leonard Richardson *suggest* a URI structure that looks friendly and easy to read.</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot, could you tell a bit more how will it work all together regarding getting all contacts, getting contacts for logged in user and getting contacts for different user then logged in

Comment: @pain.reign That's totally up to you. Any suggestions I may give you will be primarily opinion-based.